# Can't install my c# windows app with crystal reports on different computers

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Iam building windows application using c# and having crystal report in it.

My problem is that I used code that that load crystalreport.rpt file from it's location in the computer where iam developing the app.

the problem exactly in this line of code.

```
            cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");
```

Now whenever I try run the app on different computers it can't find the .rpt file and my reports don't work.

Here is the complete code.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables ;

        cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables ;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in 
CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 
    }
 }
}
```

How can I make my report work on any computer?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the path in the app.config file as key and call it from your code

OR

```
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

OR

```
 System.IO.Path.GetFullPath
```